# I want join paths between both frontend and backend and I tried a lot but only half is getting merged but not another half

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, path, production-environment

This is my server file

[I can't find any error please guide me]

```
   { const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// const router = express.Router();

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express(); //here we are going to run the express server
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(cors()); //middle ware of cors

app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB is connected man... ");
});

const nameRouter = require("./routes/name");
const addRouter = require("./routes/addstu");


app.use("/addname", nameRouter);
app.use("/add", addRouter);

//server production assests
const __dirname1 = path.resolve();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, "/public")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/public/index.html"))
  );
} 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running..");
  })
}
```

[route1]

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const Name = require("../modules/addstu");

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const names = await Name.find();
    res.json({
      sucess: "true",
      content: names,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      sucess: false,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
});

router.post("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const names = new Name(req.body);
    await names.save();
    res.json({
      success: true,
      studentId: names._id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
});

router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
 const name = Name.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(name => res.json(name))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
  Name.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(() => res.json('Student data deleted.'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.put("/", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const edit = await Name.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id);
    console.log(edit);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      studentId: edit._id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
});


router.route("/update/:id").post((req, res) => {
  Name.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
      data.name = req.body.name;
      data.email = req.body.email;
      data.phone = req.body.phone;
      data.dob = req.body.dob;
      data.gender = req.body.gender;
      data.address = req.body.address;

      data
        .save()
        .then(() => res.json("student data updated!"))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

[route2]

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const Name = require("../modules/name");

router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
     const names = await Name.find();
    res.json({
      sucess: "true",
      data : names
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      sucess: false,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
});

router.post("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const names = new Name(req.body);
    await names.save();
    res.json({
      sucess: true,
      studentId: names._id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      sucess: false,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
  // res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

[React App.js file ]

```
function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="field">
        <div className="field1">
          <Upper />
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Titlepic /> }/>
            <Route path="/studentlist" element={<div><StudentList/></div>} />
            <Route path="/add" element={<AddStudent1 />} />
            <Route path="/addname" element={<AddName />} />
            <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditStudent /> }/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried Different methods but i am getting a bug.

I tried to change routes to /api/add like that
but I faced the same problem and I can't find any issues in the code I think it has
someone take a look if I find it before I will try to update my quest.

Comment: Please don't attach code as an image - check this - [how to ask a good Q](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which bug are you getting? You should include the code of the component where the bug occurs as well.